# Summarize two numbers from one cell separately in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, split, sum, google-sheets-formula, summarize

I have multiple cells that each contain two numbers separated by a "/"

For example:

```
A1 = 10/2
A2 = 5/4
A3 = 8/1
A4 = 13/1
```

in `A5`, I would like to summarize everything on the left side of the "/" and on the right side of the "/". So A5 should have the output: `36/8`

How do I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below formula-

```
=SUM(INDEX(SPLIT(A1:A4,"/"),,1)) & "/" & SUM(INDEX(SPLIT(A1:A4,"/"),,2))
```

Also can try-

```
=JOIN("/",QUERY(INDEX(SPLIT(A1:A4,"/")),"select sum(Col1), sum(Col2) label sum(Col1) '', sum(Col2) ''"))
```

Comment: Thank you! The first one doesn't work, but the second one is perfect! Solved my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(JOIN("/", MMULT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1:A4, "/")), {1;1;1;1})))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=JOIN("/",INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(A1:A4,"/"),"select Sum(Col1), Sum(Col2)"),2))
```